# How to catch a Firebase Auth specific exceptions

Tags: java, android, exception, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase, how do I catch a specific exception and tell the user gracefully about it? E.g :

> FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The email address is badly
>   formatted.

I'm using the code below to signup the user using email and password, but I'm not that advanced in java.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            //H.toast(c, task.getException().getMessage());
            Log.e("Signup Error", "onCancelled", task.getException());
        } else {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can throw the Exception returned by `task.getException` inside a try block and catch each type of Exception that may be thrown by the method you are using.

Here is an example from the `OnCompleteListener` for the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method.

```
if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
        throw task.getException();
    } catch(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
        mTxtPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_weak_password));
        mTxtPassword.requestFocus();
    } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
        mTxtEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        mTxtEmail.requestFocus();
    } catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
        mTxtEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_user_exists));
        mTxtEmail.requestFocus();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an issue with this. Firebase just return to me a FirebaseException, not a FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException or other. but the message seems to be good : "WEAK_PASSWORD". Any idea ?

Comment: You can check the message in the final `catch` block for any exceptions that don't have a specific type.

Comment: Yes, I see it. But why do you have FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException  and I can't ? And it's bad code if I do a switch case with msg type when I should be able to do it properly with class type.

Comment: I found the Firebase framework to be inconsistent about the types of exceptions it throws. I had to check the message in some methods because of that. It is messier but you have to work with what you get. I did file a bug report but I don't think anything came of that.

Answer (score 49):

In addition to @pdegand59 answer, I found some error code in Firebase library and test on Android (the returned error code). Hope this helps, Regards.

```
 ("ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN", "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."));
 ("ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH", "The custom token corresponds to a different audience."));
 ("ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL", "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired."));
 ("ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL", "The email address is badly formatted."));
 ("ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD", "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."));
 ("ERROR_USER_MISMATCH", "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user."));
 ("ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN", "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."));
 ("ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL", "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."));
 ("ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE", "The email address is already in use by another account."));
 ("ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE", "This credential is already associated with a different user account."));
 ("ERROR_USER_DISABLED", "The user account has been disabled by an administrator."));
 ("ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED", "The user\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again."));
 ("ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND", "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."));
 ("ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN", "The user\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again."));
 ("ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED", "This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console."));
 ("ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD", "The given password is invalid."));
 ("ERROR_MISSING_EMAIL", "An email address must be provided.";
```

Answer (score 16):

There are a number of exceptions associated with firebase auth. 
In addition to @kingspeech

You should use `((FirebaseAuthException)task.getException()).getErrorCode()` to get the **type of error** and then handle it in `switch` like this :

```
private void loginUser(String email, String password) {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));

                } else {

                    String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();

                    switch (errorCode) {

                        case "ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The custom token corresponds to a different audience.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The email address is badly formatted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            etEmail.setError("The email address is badly formatted.");
                            etEmail.requestFocus();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            etPassword.setError("password is incorrect ");
                            etPassword.requestFocus();
                            etPassword.setText("");
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_USER_MISMATCH":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The email address is already in use by another account.   ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            etEmail.setError("The email address is already in use by another account.");
                            etEmail.requestFocus();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This credential is already associated with a different user account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The user account has been disabled by an administrator.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The user\\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The user\\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                        case "ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD":
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The given password is invalid.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            etPassword.setError("The password is invalid it must 6 characters at least");
                            etPassword.requestFocus();
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

**Solution using Kotlin**

```
 fun signInWithEmail(email: String, passKey: String) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, passKey).addOnSuccessListener {
        it.user?.let {
            authResultOperation.postValue(AuthResultOperation.OnSuccessSignIn)
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        val errorCode = (it.exception as FirebaseAuthException).errorCode
        val errorMessage = authErrors[errorCode] ?: R.string.error_login_default_error
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(errorMessage),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Explanation: Basically It's just a map that match firebase error codes with a custom string resource.

```
val authErrors = mapOf("ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN" to R.string.error_login_custom_token,
        "ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH" to R.string.error_login_custom_token_mismatch,
        "ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL" to R.string.error_login_credential_malformed_or_expired,
        "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL" to R.string.error_login_invalid_email,
        "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD" to R.string.error_login_wrong_password,
        "ERROR_USER_MISMATCH" to R.string.error_login_user_mismatch,
        "ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN" to R.string.error_login_requires_recent_login,
        "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL" to R.string.error_login_accounts_exits_with_different_credential,
        "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE" to  R.string.error_login_email_already_in_use,
        "ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE" to R.string.error_login_credential_already_in_use,
        "ERROR_USER_DISABLED" to R.string.error_login_user_disabled,
        "ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED" to R.string.error_login_user_token_expired,
        "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND" to R.string.error_login_user_not_found,
        "ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN" to R.string.error_login_invalid_user_token,
        "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED" to R.string.error_login_operation_not_allowed,
        "ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD" to R.string.error_login_password_is_weak)
```

String resources (Feel free to change it according to your requirements)

```
  <resources>
    <string name="error_login_custom_token">The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.</string>
    <string name="error_login_custom_token_mismatch">The custom token corresponds to a different audience.</string>
    <string name="error_login_credential_malformed_or_expired">The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.</string>
    <string name="error_login_invalid_email">The email address is badly formatted.</string>
    <string name="error_login_wrong_password">The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.</string>
    <string name="error_login_user_mismatch">The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.</string>
    <string name="error_login_requires_recent_login">This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.</string>
    <string name="error_login_accounts_exits_with_different_credential">An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.</string>
    <string name="error_login_email_already_in_use">The email address is already in use by another account.</string>
    <string name="error_login_credential_already_in_use">This credential is already associated with a different user account.</string>
    <string name="error_login_user_disabled">The user account has been disabled by an administrator.</string>
    <string name="error_login_user_not_found">There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.</string>
    <string name="error_login_operation_not_allowed">This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console.</string>
    <string name="error_login_password_is_weak">The given password is invalid.</string>
    <string name="error_login_user_token_expired">The user\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again</string>
    <string name="error_login_invalid_user_token">The user\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `((FirebaseAuthException)task.getException()).getErrorCode()` to get the type of error and fail gracefully if this is the error code for a bad formatted email.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the list of error codes used by Firebase. 
Trigger the exception once, note the error code and code accordingly.

Comment: task.getException() cannot always be cast to FirebaseAuthException, for instance when there is no network connectivity. In that case the Exception is FirebaseNetworkException

Comment: @DavidH if you use task.getException() is not null, it will fix that problem

Comment: @mehmet no, it will not fix the problem since task.getException() is not null when it is FirebaseNetworkException

Answer (score 7):

If you simply want display a message to the user this works. Simple and Elegant:

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Authentication Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It appears that the .getMessage() method converts the exception to a usable format for us already and all we have to do is display that somewhere to the user.

(This is my first comment, constructive criticism please)

Comment: This gives a warning in the `getMessage()` method saying : `Method invocation 'getMessage' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'`. How to resolve this?

Comment: It's telling you that getException() can return null so you could add... `if(task.getException != null) { Toast.makeText... }`;

Answer (score 4):

You can use either steve-guidetti or pdegand59 method. I used steve-guidetti's method(Two exceptions are missing)

For all possible exception please find below ref.

It is well documented here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

Search for "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" and find the

> **Error Codes**
>
> auth/email-already-in-use

```
Thrown if there already exists an account with the given email address.
```

> auth/invalid-email

```
Thrown if the email address is not valid.
```

> auth/operation-not-allowed

```
Thrown if email/password accounts are not enabled. Enable email/password accounts in the Firebase Console, under the Auth tab.
```

> auth/weak-password

```
Thrown if the password is not strong enough.
```

**For all five exceptions: Check here**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException

Here you can find 5 different types of AuthException. 4 Known Direct subclass and 1 indirect subclass

You can use either steve-guidetti or pdegand59 method.

Comment: This does not actually answer his question.

Comment: This is for Auth Specific right, two more exceptions are missing. Check the reference

Comment: He asked "how do I catch a specific exception and tell the user gracefully about it" not "give me a list of exceptions that are possible".  Your answer does not help with either of those things -- how to catch the exception, or how to inform the user about it.

Comment: This is for web (Javascript) not for Android development.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending upstream messages from user to cloud, implement firebase callback functions `onMessageSent` and `onSendError` to check the status of upstream messages. In error cases, `onSendError` returns a **SendException** with an error code.

For example, if the client attempts to send more messages after the 20-message limit is reached, it returns **SendException#ERROR_TOO_MANY_MESSAGES.**

Answer (score 2):

To catch a firebase Exception is easy, you should add `.addOnFailureListener` after you add `.addOnCompleteListener` like this:

```
 private void login_user(String email, String password) {

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()){
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
           }if(!task.isSuccessful()){


                // To know The Excepton 
                //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            if( e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This User Not Found , Create A New Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if( e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The Password Is Invalid, Please Try Valid Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(e instanceof FirebaseNetworkException){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Check Your Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Isn' this a little cumbersome?.. Compared to the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another solutions but didn't like them.

What about this:

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

    Exception exc = task.getException();

    if (exc.getMessage().contains("The email address is badly formatted.")) {
        etUser.setError(getString(R.string.error_wrong_email));
        etUser.requestFocus();
    }
    else
    if (exc.getMessage().contains("There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.")) {
        etUser.setError(getString(R.string.error_user_not_exist));
        etUser.requestFocus();
    }
    else
    if (exc.getMessage().contains("The password is invalid or the user does not have a password")) {
        etPass.setError(getString(R.string.error_wrong_password));
        etPass.requestFocus();
    }


    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());


    Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**LOGIN_EXCEPTIONS**

`FirebaseAuthException` - Generic exception related to Firebase Authentication. Check the error code and message for more details.

`ERROR_USER_DISABLE`D if the user has been disabled (for example, in the Firebase console)

`ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND` if the user has been deleted (for example, in the Firebase console, or in another instance of this app)

`ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED` if the user's token has been revoked in the backend. This happens automatically if the user's credentials change in another device (for example, on a password change event).

`ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN` if the user's token is malformed. This should not happen under normal circumstances.

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)
  .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          if(task.isSuccessful())
            {

            }else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {

            }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_USER_DISABLED"))
            {

           }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND "))
          {

          }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED "))
         {

         }else if(((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN "))
         {
         }
 }
});
```

**REGISTER_EXCEPTIONS**

```
FirebaseAuthEmailException
```

Represents the exception which is a result of an attempt to send an email via Firebase Auth (e.g. a password reset email)

`FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` - Thrown when one or more of the credentials passed to a method fail to identify and/or authenticate the user subject of that operation. Inspect the error code and message to find out the specific cause.

`FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` - Thrown when using a weak password (less than 6 chars) to create a new account or to update an existing account's password. Use getReason() to get a message with the reason the validation failed that you can display to your users.

Answer (score 1):

According to me the default message is informative enough. So I used it rather than any custom message and it worked pretty well for me.

```java
if (!task.isSuccessful()) 
{ 
    // there was an error
    String yourString = task.getException().toString();
    String target = "Exception:";
    String error = yourString.substring(yourString.indexOf(target) + target.length() + 1, yourString.length());
    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Error: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

p.s. this is my first answer on stack overflow. Do let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
            throw task.getException();
        } catch(FirebaseAuthException e) {
           switch (e.getErrorCode()){
                        case "ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD":
                      Toast.makeText(this, "The given password is invalid.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             break;
                      //and other
                    }
        }
```

error codes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244409/2425851

Answer (score 0):

In the past we used the getErrorCode() to get the type of error and fail gracefully. With the newer versions of the api, getErrorCode() is deprecated. We should use response.getError().getErrorCode() instead

```
com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse
@Deprecated 
public int getErrorCode()
Get the error code for a failed sign in

Deprecated use getError() instead
```

So for e.g.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                    IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

                    // Successfully signed in
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        //dbHandler = DBMS.getInstance(this);

                        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();

                        // initialize profile first
                        if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {



                            //start main activity after profile setup
                            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                            return;
                        } else {
                            // This is an existing user
                            // show them a welcome back screen.

                            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed
                        // check response for error code
                        if (response == null) {
                            // User pressed back button
                            showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
                            return;
                        }

                        if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                            showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection);
                            return;
                        }

                        if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                            showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_error);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_sign_in_response);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        throw task.getException();
    }
    // if user enters wrong email.
    catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException weakPassword) {
        Log.d("Registration Error", "onComplete: weak_password");

        // TODO: take your actions!
    }
    // if user enters wrong password.
    catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException malformedEmail) {
        Log.d("Registration Error", "onComplete: malformed_email");

        // TODO: Take your action
    }
    catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException existEmail) {
        Log.d("Registration Error", "onComplete: exist_email");

        // TODO: Take your action
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Registration Error", "onComplete: " + e.getMessage());
    }
} else {
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR, Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many Firebase Authentication exceptions to handle, and I'm not sure if handling all of them is a good thing due to a large amount of code to add (as you can see from other answers).

I just got a `FirebaseTooManyRequestsException` after `Task<AuthResult.isSuccessful()` returned  false:

```
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                [...]
            } else {
                [FirebaseTooManyRequestsException and others that can be returned here]
            }
        }
```

`com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later. [ Access to this account has been temporarily disabled due to many failed login attempts. You can immediately restore it by resetting your password or you can try again later. ]`

[image: FirebaseTooManyRequestsException]

So, if you want to catch all of them or at least the ones that are more important to your logic, I hope that bringing another FirebaseAuth exception to this list helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `Kotlin` parser that I use. it's adapted from [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/util/FirebaseAuthError.java)

```
/**
 * List of all possible results of [FirebaseAuthException.getErrorCode] and their meanings.
 * TODO you can make description parameter private if you don't use it outside of this class
 */
enum class FirebaseAuthErrorParser(val description: String) {
    ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN("The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."),
    ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH("Invalid configuration. Ensure your app's SHA1 is correct in the Firebase console."),
    ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL("The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired."),
    ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL("The email address is badly formatted."),
    ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD("The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."),
    ERROR_USER_MISMATCH("The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user."),
    ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN("This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."),
    ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL("An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."),
    ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE("The email address is already in use by another account."),
    ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE("This credential is already associated with a different user account."),
    ERROR_USER_DISABLED("The user account has been disabled by an administrator."),
    ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED("The user's credential has expired. The user must sign in again."),
    ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND("There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."),
    ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN("The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again."),
    ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED("This operation is not allowed. Enable the sign-in method in the Authentication tab of the Firebase console"),
    ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS("We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later."),
    ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD("The given password is too weak, please choose a stronger password."),
    ERROR_EXPIRED_ACTION_CODE("The out of band code has expired."),
    ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_CODE("The out of band code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used."),
    ERROR_INVALID_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD("The email template corresponding to this action contains invalid characters in its message. Please fix by going to the Auth email templates section in the Firebase Console."),
    ERROR_INVALID_RECIPIENT_EMAIL("The email corresponding to this action failed to send as the provided recipient email address is invalid."),
    ERROR_INVALID_SENDER("The email template corresponding to this action contains an invalid sender email or name. Please fix by going to the Auth email templates section in the Firebase Console."),
    ERROR_MISSING_EMAIL("An email address must be provided."),
    ERROR_MISSING_PASSWORD("A password must be provided."),
    ERROR_MISSING_PHONE_NUMBER("To send verification codes, provide a phone number for the recipient."),
    ERROR_INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER("The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code]."),
    ERROR_MISSING_VERIFICATION_CODE("The phone auth credential was created with an empty sms verification code"),
    ERROR_INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE("The sms verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code sms and be sure use the verification code provided by the user."),
    ERROR_MISSING_VERIFICATION_ID("The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID"),
    ERROR_INVALID_VERIFICATION_ID("The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid."),
    ERROR_RETRY_PHONE_AUTH("An error occurred during authentication using the PhoneAuthCredential. Please retry authentication."),
    ERROR_SESSION_EXPIRED("The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again."),
    ERROR_QUOTA_EXCEEDED("The sms quota for this project has been exceeded."),
    ERROR_APP_NOT_AUTHORIZED("This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console."),
    ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE("The API that you are calling is not available on devices without Google Play Services."),
    ERROR_WEB_CONTEXT_CANCELED("The web operation was canceled by the user"),
    ERROR_UNKNOWN("An unknown error occurred.");


    companion object {
        /**
         * Get an [FirebaseAuthError.description] from an exception,
         * returning [FirebaseAuthError.ERROR_UNKNOWN] as a default.
         */
        fun fromException(ex: FirebaseAuthException): String {
            return try {
                valueOf(ex.errorCode).description
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.e(TAG, e)
                ERROR_UNKNOWN.description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
val ErrorMsg = FirebaseAuthErrorParser.fromException(firebaseAuthEx)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(authCredential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed. " + task.getException().toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.