# How do you retrieve the error code from a Firebase Task<AuthResult> unsuccessful login?

Tags: android, authentication, error-handling, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently wondering how it is possible to gain the error code after carrying out an unsuccessful login using `Firebase`. From their legacy code, that you can see in this link below:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-handling-errors

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError error) {
    switch (error.getCode()) {
        case FirebaseError.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
            // handle a non existing user
            break;
        case FirebaseError.INVALID_PASSWORD:
            // handle an invalid password
            break;
        default:
            // handle other errors
            break;
    }
}
```

You are provided an `onAuthenticationError`, where the `FirebaseError` can then be specifically analysed to produce a different feedback error to the user. However as they have recently released their new API, I have started to work with that. Here is the code I have to utilise now:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    //If authentication fails
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        // Handle the specific individual errors such as incorrect passwords
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how I am able to gather the specific error code from the `Task<AuthResult>` object. I understand that I can gather the `Exception` and `Toast` this message, although I would prefer to carry out a switch on a proper error code rather than work with a `String` explaining the error that occurred.

Comment: You can refer from my answer here, I think it will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/37860491/5303797

Comment: do not use `FirebaseError` class because from the documentation `Represents API errors. This is for internal usage only and we don't expose externally.`

Answer (score 4):

If your code already has onCompleteListener then I won't recommend you to add onFailureListner just get information about the exception because it will increase the number of listeners.
You can get an error code and message as follow.

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    //If authentication fails
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
        String localizedMessage = task.getException().getLocalizedMessage();
        String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
    }
}
```

I will recommend using Localized Message instead of just Message because a Localized message is short and has enough the information necessary to tackle the error.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add the `onFailureListner()`
with the code below you can get the error code :

```
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
    notifyUser("Invalid password");
} else if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {

    String errorCode = 
    ((FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) e).getErrorCode();

    if (errorCode.equals("ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND")) {
        notifyUser("No matching account found");
    } else if (errorCode.equals("ERROR_USER_DISABLED")) {
        notifyUser("User account has been disabled");
    } else {
        notifyUser(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
            }
     });
```

notifyUser() method you should develop to show Toast or snackbar or dialog maybe

Answer (score 1):

I'd struggled with this a bit, but found the answer. give it a try:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication completed.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication failed:" +      
        task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

to get the exception i'd used: `task.getException()`.

good luck

Answer (score -1):

Better to use

```
task.getException().getMessage()
```

to get well formated message for user