# fatal exception while signing up user with firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have created one of my functions for signing the user up with Firebase. However, I have kept getting an else response from my if statement saying that there was a problem with signing up a new user.

Therefore I have changed my `if !task.isSuccessful()` statement to print an exception.

```
--------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.user.myapp, PID: 2794
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException
                      at com.example.user.myapp.MainActivity$3.onComplete(MainActivity.java:91)
                      at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) Application terminated.
```

Here is my sign up function:

```
private void signupUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this,
            new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was a problem with your registration. Please try again.",
                        //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException )task.getException();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Registration: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have successfuly signed up.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createUserProfile();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You got an exception while trying to print an exception. Try logging this: FirebaseException e = task.getException();

Comment: and post it here

Comment: it does not let me do this because it requires FirebaseAuthException. So if I remove (FirebaseAuthException ) it gives me red underline in android studio.

Comment: You can cast to FirebaseException, as FirebaseAuthException extends it

Comment: FirebaseException e =(FirebaseException) task.getException()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859582/how-to-catch-a-firebase-auth-specific-exceptions --> this will resolve your concern

Comment: Now my FirebaseException prints: Access not configured: Google Identity toolkit API has not been used in project.