# check existing and none existing account in firebase auth / Android Java

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Is there any way on how to check if the input email and password is incorrect and if the input email and password is not existing?

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                    // ...
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

I know, basically else clause display if the sign in failed. But I wanna know on how do I display the TOAST if the EMAIL is existing but WRONG LOGIN CREDENTIALS and if the input EMAIL is not existing at all. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch a Firebase Auth specific exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859582/how-to-catch-a-firebase-auth-specific-exceptions)

Comment: @codearn19 hello, I just tried it right now, but why it wont print the toast message?
`try {
                                        throw task.getException();
                                   }
                                   catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e){
                                       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       userID.setText("");
                                       password.setText("");

                                   }`

Comment: @codearn19, thank you had to tweak some of the code and it worked. Thank you!